# What are the advantages of running elasticsearch on CoreOS (with Docker) instead of Ubuntu

Tags: elasticsearch, coreos

I'm very new to CoreOS / Docker, so could you please explain what advantages (or disadvantages) there are with running elasticsearch nodes on CoreOS machines instead of plain old Ubuntu machines.

I was thinking of following this [tutorial](http://mattupstate.com/coreos/devops/2014/06/26/running-an-elasticsearch-cluster-on-coreos.html) to get going, but I'd like first to know what gains can be made:

- Will it use more/less RAM overall than on Ubuntu?
- Will it use CPU power more "intelligently" than on on Ubuntu

Comment: In theory: "CoreOS is designed to be a modern, minimal base to build your platform. Consumes 40% less RAM on boot than an average Linux installation". And I'm using it to implement dev, qa and production workflow and it's very interesting because CoreOS integrate all you will need(minimum requirement: RAM, docker, service discovery with etcd vs consul).

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure that in overall elasticsearch over coreOS will consume less RAM or CPU if you deploy it over CoreOS with Docker, since the Docker itself contains an OS (probably ubuntu).

The main advantage of CoreOS over regular Ubuntu deploying is Fleet, which gives you easy-to-deploy cluster management with high availability.

Answer (score 1):

You will optimise your ressource usage by running containers, as the scheduler (fleet) will distribute the load over your CoreOS cluster and balance it. It will be definitely more cost efficient and time saving.

Moreover, you will not have to care about any server configuration, just start your CoreOS server, run `fleetctl start <your unit>` and your app will be available. On server in the cluster goes down, just replace it and everything restarts.

Using CoreOS, you can stop considering your servers as units. You consider them as a pool of ressources available to use by your containers, attributed automatically or manually depending on your choosing.